# How to handle sessions in Laravel 5 with the Parse SDK?

Tags: php, laravel, parse-platform, laravel-5

I'm building an app using the Parse PHP SDK in Laravel 5 (I use ["Laravel-Parse" by Graham Campbell](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Parse) for the Parse SDK integration).

I am able to create a user with this code :

```
$user = new ParseUser();
$user->setUsername($username);
$user->setEmail($email);
$user->setPassword($password);

try {
    $user->signUp();
} catch (ParseException $ex) {
    // error in $ex->getMessage();
}
```

... then I can log-in :

```
try {
    $user = ParseUser::logIn($username, $password);
} catch(ParseException $ex) {
    // error in $ex->getMessage();
}
```

and just after this code, I can get the current user from Parse :

```
$user = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();
```

The "getCurrentUser()" function returns the current user if I execute this code just after the Parse login function. However, if I go to another page in my Laravel website, and try to get the current user again with the same code, I get an empty array.

I guess it is a session error, can you tell me if I missed anything ? Or how to fix that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to set Parse to use Laravel's Session implementation. Parse looks to use the native PHP Sessions. Parse explains, in not much detail, in their documentation https://parse.com/docs/php/guide#users-session-storage-interface

I've actually created a class already for this that you could use 
https://gist.github.com/anthonyholmes/608be72d1914fad23885